# react filter a nested object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I got some data with this kind of structure from a public API. My objective is to create a function that can filter the data by its name of the type (e.g sedan).

```
const arrayData = 
[
"0" : {
 "car" : {
      "0" : {
       "type": {
           name: "sedan", 
           condition: "new"
       }
   },
      "1" : {
       "type": {
           name: "minivan", 
           condition: "new"
       }
    }
  }
},

"1" : {
 "car" : {
      "0" : {
       "type": {
           name: "sedan", 
           condition: "new"
       }
   },
  }
},

"2" : {
 "car" : {
      "0" : {
       "type": {
           name: "minivan", 
           condition: "new"
       }
    }
  }
},
]
```

This is an example of my function

```
const filterData = (types) => {
    let filteredData = [...arrayData];
    filteredData = filteredData.map((data) => {
      data.car.map((type) => {
        if (types === type.type.name) {
          return types;
        }
        return type;
      });
      return data;
    });
    console.log(filteredData);
  };
```

I expected it will only show the data that includes the types that were cathed as the parameter. Is there a way for me to achieve that?

Comment: Try to use lodash filter.
That will make you life simple.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter

Comment: The `arrayData`  value is wrong. If you console it, you will get an error.